# Replace all partial string entries with NA

Tags: r

I have a data frame similar to:

```
df<-as.data.frame(cbind(rep("Canada",6), 
                          c(rep("Alberta",3), rep("Manitoba",2),rep("Unknown_province",1)), 
                          c("Edmonton", "Unknown_city","Unknown_city","Brandon","Unknown_city","Unknown_city")))

colnames(df)<- c("Country","Province","City")
```

I would like to substitute all entries that contain "Unknown" with NA.

I have tried using grepl, but it removes all entries for that variable if one entry matches, I would like to only replace individual cells.

df[grepl("Unknown", df, ignore.case=TRUE)] <- NA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one possible way to solve your problem:

```
df[] <- lapply(df, function(x) ifelse(grepl("Unknown", x, TRUE), NA, x))
df

#   Country Province     City
# 1  Canada  Alberta Edmonton
# 2  Canada  Alberta     <NA>
# 3  Canada  Alberta     <NA>
# 4  Canada Manitoba  Brandon
# 5  Canada Manitoba     <NA>
# 6  Canada     <NA>     <NA>
```

Answer (score 4):

```
df1 <- df # This is to ensure that we can refert back to df incase there is an issue
```

Then you could use any of the following:

```
is.na(df1) <- array(grepl('Unknown', as.matrix(df1)), dim(df1))
df1
  Country Province     City
1  Canada  Alberta Edmonton
2  Canada  Alberta     <NA>
3  Canada  Alberta     <NA>
4  Canada Manitoba  Brandon
5  Canada Manitoba     <NA>
6  Canada     <NA>     <NA>
```

or even:

```
df1[] <- sub("Unknown.*", NA, as.matrix(df1), ignore.case = TRUE)
df1
  Country Province     City
1  Canada  Alberta Edmonton
2  Canada  Alberta     <NA>
3  Canada  Alberta     <NA>
4  Canada Manitoba  Brandon
5  Canada Manitoba     <NA>
6  Canada     <NA>     <NA>
```

Note that `grepl` and even `sub` are `vectorized` hence no need to use the `*aply` family or even for loops

Answer (score 2):

Using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>% 
    mutate(across(everything(),
    ~ case_when(str_detect(., 'Unknown', negate = TRUE) ~  .)))
  Country Province     City
1  Canada  Alberta Edmonton
2  Canada  Alberta     <NA>
3  Canada  Alberta     <NA>
4  Canada Manitoba  Brandon
5  Canada Manitoba     <NA>
6  Canada     <NA>     <NA>
```

Answer (score 1):

I like to use `replace()` in such cases in which values in a vector are `replace`d or left as is, depending on a condition :

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df%>%mutate(across(everything(), ~replace(.x, str_detect(.x, 'Unknown'), NA)))

  Country Province     City
1  Canada  Alberta Edmonton
2  Canada  Alberta     <NA>
3  Canada  Alberta     <NA>
4  Canada Manitoba  Brandon
5  Canada Manitoba     <NA>
6  Canada     <NA>     <NA>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df[]<- lapply(df, gsub, pattern = "Unknown", replacement = NA, fixed = TRUE)
```